# Android PreferenceActivity

Tags: android

I have my prefence options like this:

```
public class Opciones extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.opciones);

        SharedPreferences sp = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();

        EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference( "opcCodigo" );
        editTextPref.setSummary(sp.getString("opcCodigo", ""));

        EditTextPreference editTextPref2 = (EditTextPreference) findPreference( "opcUrl" );
        editTextPref2.setSummary(sp.getString("opcUrl", ""));
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Preference pref = findPreference(key);
        if (pref instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) pref;
            pref.setSummary(etp.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

The fact is that when I change the data, the fields are not refreshed, I have to close the activity and launch it again to see them.

Whats I´m missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement OnPreferenceChangeListener and override the following method.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
      //newValue is the edited data
      if(editTextPref == preference) editTextPref.setSummary(newValue);
      else editTextPref2.setSummary(newValue);
 }
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? PreferenceActivity doesn't even have an onPreferenceChange() method to override.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
1. Add **OnSharedPreferenceChangeListner**

```
public class Opciones extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

2. And **Override** method **onSharedPreferenceChanged**

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key){
   // ...
}
```

Comment: To use this though, you need to get the preferences from your activity with getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences() and then use registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() with your GLOBAL VARIABLE (so it won't be garbage collected) OnSharedPreferenceChangeListner as the argument.